# Is this schema secure?

Tags: rsa, signature, blind-signature

I want to know if we use function `H` as random oracle in [RSA Blind Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature) and assume that [RSA Assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_RSA_assumption) is correct, is it true that the `RSA blind signature` schema is secure?(i.e. There isn't any adversary who can create a valid signature on a message that he doesn't queried to `signer oracle`). Intuitively, I think this is true, but I can't prove it formally. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You might want to add a little more detail in the title.

Comment: I am not aware of a technique to prove it under the RSA assumption. But you can prove it in the random oracle model under the stronger one-more RSA assumption:  http://eprint.iacr.org/2001/002

Answer (score 1):

Blind signature works as follows:

(1) User blinds a message $M$ with blinding factor $b$ raise to the public key of the signer $e$ as $ b^e \cdot M $

(2) the signer will blindly sign the value by raising it to its private key $d$, as $ \sigma'^d = b \cdot M^d $

(3) the user will compute the signature $\sigma$ by multiplying $\sigma'$ by $b^{-1}$ as $\sigma = M^d$.

To forge a valid signature without needing the signer, you can start by an inverse process i.e. create a garbage message and signature pair $<\sigma=M,message=M^e>$.

This will work because when the verifier wants to check the validity of the message, signature pair it will raise the signature $\sigma$ to the public exponent $e$ and it will match. The down point for this is that the adversary will have rubbish message.

Comment: It looks you consider that H(m) = m, but I said H is random oracle.